# Touchpad on Lenovo x240 missing features after suspend

Tags: 18.04, suspend, touchpad, lenovo

I have installed the new Ubuntu 18.04 on my Lenovo Thinkpad X240 and 
everthing is doing fine on startup.

My problem is showing up after waking up from suspend mode.
Features like two finger scrolling and two finger tap for rightclick 
are not working anymore.

I have read some solutions about using hibernate instead of suspend,
but this may only be a workaround and not a solution to my problem.

So i would appreciate any suggestions and solutions.
Just as a side information: It is no dual boot system. Only Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Hi A-G - probably not much help 'cause I'm no expert but just something that might be worth ruling out - when you come back from suspend, check the system settings in case somehow something weird has happened with them. Make sure the Tap to Click and Two-finger Scrolling settings haven't oddly decided to be 'off'. Click them off and back on a couple of times and see if it makes a difference. If not then you'll have to investigate a bit more - unfortunately I don't know what'd be the best way to go about doing that.

Comment: Hi pHeLiOn, first of all thanks for your answer.
Checking the system settings shows that everything is like it should be, but the problem is not fixed. 
Also reconfiguring the settings has no effect. 
Maybe this is a new hint for the solution :D - But thx anyway!

Comment: Ah, sorry there wasn't an easy fix :( I was hoping maybe the settings were just turning off but, although it's probably not the correct terminology, it sounds more like the driver for the touchpad isn't initialising properly on wakeup. I suppose you could try seeing what other people have done when bits of their hardware haven't 'woken up' properly and see if there are any clues in their solutions as to how to investigate further...

Comment: Found someone experiencing problems with their keyboard not 'waking up' after resume from suspend: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061565/keyboard-uunresponsive-after-resume-from-suspend - might help put you on the right track to investigating your touchpad issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1722478/comments/44):

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=0"

It worked for me.